# How the interface works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, interface

These code are from http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html 
My question is about "How interfaces work?" For example, why in the first part we used cell.minHeight(), not just cell? Why we need .minHeight() and how it work later? Author didn't explain how interfaces work :(

```js
function rowHeights(rows) {
  return rows.map(function(row) {
    return row.reduce(function(max, cell) {
      return Math.max(max, cell.minHeight());
    }, 0);
  });
}

function colWidths(rows) {
  return rows[0].map(function(_, i) {
    return rows.reduce(function(max, row) {
      return Math.max(max, row[i].minWidth());
    }, 0);
  });
}
```

Also I see draw(width, height) and arguments that it receives, but I don't understand what code executed?

```js
function drawTable(rows) {
  var heights = rowHeights(rows);
  var widths = colWidths(rows);

  function drawLine(blocks, lineNo) {
    return blocks.map(function(block) {
      return block[lineNo];
    }).join(" ");
  }

  function drawRow(row, rowNum) {
    var blocks = row.map(function(cell, colNum) {
      return cell.draw(widths[colNum], heights[rowNum]);
    });
    return blocks[0].map(function(_, lineNo) {
      return drawLine(blocks, lineNo);
    }).join("\n");
  }

  return rows.map(drawRow).join("\n");
}
```

And is there a connection between the ad minHeight() and minWidth() above and referred to in this piece of code?

```js
function UnderlinedCell(inner) {
  this.inner = inner;
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.minWidth = function() {
  return this.inner.minWidth();
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.minHeight = function() {
  return this.inner.minHeight() + 1;
};
UnderlinedCell.prototype.draw = function(width, height) {
  return this.inner.draw(width, height - 1)
    .concat([repeat("-", width)]);
};
```

Simple example:

```js
davey = {
    name: "Davey"
}

john = {
    name: "John"
}

say = function(){
        alert("Hello, I'm " + this.name)
}

davey.sayHi = say
john.sayHi = say

davey.sayHi() // =>  Hello, I'm Davey
john.sayHi() // =>  Hello, I'm Jhon
```

It's mean, somewhere we should have function minHeight(). But, as I understand interfaces work otherwise, and I don't understand how.

Comment: What don't you understand about those codes? What parts of it do you understand?

Comment: the odd thing is, it's all explained in the link you provided

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, i try to clarify. My question is about "How  interfaces work?" For example, why in the first part we used cell.minHeight(), not just cell? Why we need .minHeight() and how it work later? Author didn't explain how interfaces work :(

Comment: @Bergi I understand all code, exception why we need .minHeight(), .minWidth(), .draw(), and how interfaces connection in different part of code?

Comment: "How interfaces work?" javascript doesnt have interfaces. Maybe thats where you misunderstanding is coming from. in the examples you have it's simply an object that has a method.

Comment: @atmd Quote of the author: "This is the interface:

 minHeight() returns a number indicating the minimum height this cell requires (in lines).

 minWidth() returns a number indicating this cell’s minimum width (in characters).
 draw(width, height) returns an array of length height, which contains a series of strings that are each width characters wide. This represents the content of the cell." It's mean somewhere in code we should have description those method, how they will be do it. But I don't see it.

Comment: just because he's using the word 'interface' doesnt make it so, he could have said it was a chicken but it still wouldnt be the case. ES6 allows classes in the traditional sense, but even then not interfaces. I believe the author is using interface to mean more of a facade, where by it's the public api that other code inteacts with, but it isnt an interface, and javascript does not have interfaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do interfaces work?

An [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming)) is a convention. This convention states how a kind of objects is expected to look like, including what methods it should have, what signatures theses methods are expected to have and what they are supposed to do.

JavaScript does not have interfaces as a language element (like e.g. Java does), they are pure convention. In your case, a convention for cell objects is defined simply in the text:

> This is the interface:
>
> - `minHeight()` returns a number indicating the minimum height this cell requires (in lines).
> - `minWidth()` returns a number indicating this cell’s minimum width (in characters).
> - `draw(width, height)` returns an array of length height, which contains a series of strings that are each width characters wide. This
>     represents the content of the cell.

As the author explains:

> The layout program will communicate with the cell objects through a
>   well-defined interface. That way, the types of cells that the program
>   supports is not fixed in advance. We can add new cell styles later—for
>   example, underlined cells for table headers—and if they support our
>   interface, they will just work, without requiring changes to the
>   layout program.

So your `drawTable` function expects to get an array of arrays of such cell objects. So let's play a game: Cell or no cell?

```
{}
```

> empty object, no methods: no cell!

```
{ minHeight: function() { return 3; },
  minWidth: function() { return 3; } }
```

> no `draw` method: no cell!

```
new TextCell("Hi")
```

> inherits methods from `TextCell.prototye`, which perform as expected: cell

```
{ minHeight: function() { return 3; },
  minWidth: function() { return 3; },
  draw: function() { return []; } }
```

> `draw` method doesn't take `width` and `height` parameters, and always returns an empty array: no cell.

```
new RTextCell("Hi")
```

> inherits methods from `RTextCell.prototye` and `TextCell.prototye`, which perform as expected: cell

```
{ minHeight: function() { return 3; },
  minWidth: function() { return 3; },
  draw: function(w, h) { 
      var t = new Array(w-1).join("-");
      return return [","+t+"."].concat(new TextCell("").draw(w-2, h-2).map(function(l) {
          return "|"+l+"|";
      }), ["`"+t+"´"]);
  } }
```

> has required methods and those behave as expected: cell!